# Why am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, knex.js

```
if (arguments.length === 0 || !config.client && !config.dialect) {
                                    ^
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your config variable is undefined. You should probably check it's value.

Comment: @Asteriscus the real problem here is not the code of the question, it's that the asker didn't give the base context. This is an error generated from the module Knex in Node.js, from inside the module. Knex is complaining that it's not getting data that it expect. . . but if his code is anything like mine, then he's giving it the data, but Knex is complaining anyway. Here's a better build of the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379839/undefined-db-connection-with-knex?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The `config` variable is `undefined`. You should check it to before reading the values of `config.client` and `config.dialect`

```
if (arguments.length === 0 || (config && !config.client && !config.dialect))
```

Keep in minds that if config is `undefined`, the evaluation of the right expression in the `OR` clause will be false

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue as well.  In my code I'm initializing knex in the following way.

`const knex = require('knex')(process.env.DATABASE_URL)`

When I checked the value of `process.env.DATABASE_URL` I discovered that it was undefined.  Once I fixed that, the error went away!  (In my case I had my .env file in the wrong place)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the issue is with the import of Minio especially in the Typescript environment. In that case, import Minio as follows:

```
import * as Minio from 'minio';
```